# How can we convert pandas dataframe two columns to python list after merging two columns vertically?

Tags: pandas, list, dataframe

I have a dataframe...

```
print(df)       
Name    ae_rank    adf      de_rank
a       1          lk       4   
b       2          lp       5
c       3          yi       6
```

How can I concat **ae_rank column** and **de_rank column** vertically and convert them into python list.

Expectation...

```
my_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Answer (score 0):

Simpliest is join lists:

```
my_list =  df['ae_rank'].tolist() + df['de_rank'].tolist()
```

If need reshape DataFrame with [`DataFrame.melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html):

```
my_list = df.melt(['Name','adf'])['value'].tolist()
print (my_list )
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is

```
my_list = df[['ae_rank', 'de_rank']].T.stack().tolist()
#[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Answer (score 0):

Most efficiently, use [`filter`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html) to select the columns by name that include "_rank" and use the underlying numpy array with [`ravel`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html) on the 'F' order (column major order):

```
my_list = df.filter(like='_rank').to_numpy().ravel('F').tolist()
```

output: `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]`